# Read Chunk of data from file based on offset and length

Tags: c#

```cs
int n = 0;
string encodeString = string.Empty;
using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
    n = fsSource.Read(bytes, offset, count);
    encodeString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
```

The above code is working fine if I provide offset-0 and length-1024, but the second time if I provide Offset-1024 and length-1024 it is returning an error.

My requirement is I want to get byte array data from offset to length.

1st chunk = 0-1024
2nd chunk = 1024-2048
..
Last chunk = SomeValue -Filesize.

Example in Node.js using `readChunk.sync(file_path, Number(offset), Number(size));` - this code is able to get the byte array of data from offset to length.

Comment: `offset, count` parameters refer to the offset into the array, not the file. The file is just read from wherever the current seek position is, which is where you left off last time. See docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=net-5.0#system-io-filestream-read(system-byte-system-int32-system-int32)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
        public static string ReadFileStreamInChunks()
        {
            const int readChunkBufferLength = 1024;
            string filePath = "test.pdf";
            string encodeString = string.Empty;
            var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
            int readChunkLength;
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                do
                {
                    readChunkLength = sr.ReadBlock(readChunk, 0, readChunkBufferLength);
                    sw.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
                } while (readChunkLength > 0);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i think your problem is understanding the concepts of these parameters in your code , Count is your Chunk Size and offset is where to start Reading so if you want to read (1): a part of File to end Just Add To Your Offset (Offset + count of Bytes you Want To Seek) but (2): if You Want to Read A Part Of File From Middle You Shouldn't Modify Count That Is Your Chunk Size You Should modify Where You Write Your Byte Array Usually It's a Do-While Loop like :

```
               long position = 0;               
               do
                {
                    // read bytes from input stream
                    int bytesRead = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
                    if (bytesRead == 0) 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    // write bytes to output stream
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    position += bytesRead;
                                            
                    if(position == "the value you want")
                     break;

                } while (true);
```